# How to ignore modules from the karma config file with browserify

Tags: testing, reactjs, karma-runner, browserify

I'm trying to test React.js with testdom, which requires jsdom.
I'm using karma with browserify.
jsdom cannot be browserified, so I'd like to ignore it.

The problem I have is trying to do this from within the karma.config.js file.

```
browserify: {
    debug: true,
    transform: [
      "babelify"
    ],
    ignore: [] or {} or...???
  },
```

Comment: did you try both, `[]` and `{}`? Didn't they work?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @marcel for the answer.
I'm not sure why it failed to work in my case (using `exclude` and `ignore`)
But I managed to get what I needed from this...

`browserify: {
 debug: true,
    transform: [
        "babelify"
    ],
    configure: function(bundle) {
      bundle.on('prebundle', function() {
        bundle.ignore('jsdom');
      });
    }
  }`

Which you might have guessed, registers a callback for 'prebundle', where you can configure the bundle. From the karma-browserify docs: https://github.com/Nikku/karma-browserify#additional-bundle-configuration

Not the cleanest, but it worked. I've since dropped my need for testdom/jsdom.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for this. I wonder why `ignore: ['things']` doesn't work . . .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
browserify: {
    debug: true,
    transform: [
        "babelify"
    ],
    exclude: [
        "jsdom"
    ]
},
```

`exclude` will omit the files from the output bundle. You could also try `ignore`: that would replace the files with empty stubs.